# Create SOInvoice and override Ship-to-contact

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create an SOInvoice but the overwrite does not work in the Address section

the header works fine but the address section doesn't

this is my code

```
SOInvoiceEntry sOInvoiceEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOInvoiceEntry>();
ARInvoice aRInvoice = new ARInvoice();
```

so, i try to override like this

```
ARAddress aRAddress = new ARAddress();
aRAddress.OverrideAddress = true;

aRAddress.AddressLine1 = header.BillToAddressLine1;
aRAddress.AddressLine2 = header.BillToAddressLine2;
aRAddress.City = header.BillToCity;
aRAddress.CountryID = header.BillToCountryID;
aRAddress.State = header.BillToState;
aRAddress.PostalCode = header.BillToPostalCode;

//then I insert de address
sOInvoiceEntry.Billing_Address.Insert(aRAddress);

//and finally save
sOInvoiceEntry.Actions.PressSave();
```

this does not give me any error but the overwride does not work
[override does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojgUO.png)

Answer (score 1):

I did this for the shipping address on the sales order but should work similarly

```
            SOShippingAddress shippingAddress = graph.Shipping_Address.Current = graph.Shipping_Address.Select();

            shippingAddress.OverrideAddress = true;
            graph.Shipping_Address.Update(shippingAddress);
            shippingAddress = graph.Shipping_Address.Current;

            shippingAddress.AddressLine1 = line.AddressLine1;
            shippingAddress.AddressLine2 = line.AddressLine2;
            shippingAddress.AddressLine3 = line.AddressLine3;
            shippingAddress.City         = line.City;
            shippingAddress.State        = line.State;
            shippingAddress.PostalCode   = line.PostalCode;

            graph.Shipping_Address.Update(shippingAddress);
            graph.Shipping_Address.Cache.IsDirty = true;
```